# How do I implement online/offline feature with REST based application?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web-applications

I am building a chat feature(web application) where in the user has a list of friends he can chat with. Friends can be online or offline, like in Facebook. Since, the application is built on REST apis, I don't save the session and all of the authentication is stateless.

So my question is, how do I know who is online or offline among the list? What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for chat applications you just send a message from client to server after some set time period, if message is not received, then the user is offline.

I am not Java developer, but I would suggest you look into `WebSockets` for your chat. Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't have to be Java, rather the approach I am looking at.

Comment: Then I would definetly suggest you http://socket.io and check their demo page. Brutally simple.

Answer (score 0):

Create two different channel categories, one for the friends and the other for the actual messages. You can then send updates to the friends channel when friends join / leave.

Each client will then have two subscriptions

eg `/friends/xxx` and `/chatMessages/xxx` where xxx is a userid (or maybe a the chat room's name)

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer the question. How do I know who is online?

Comment: When someone joins, you lookup all the online friends and send a FriendJoined message to each online friend's `friend` channel. And when they leave, you send a FriendLeft message etc.

Comment: I've implemented user list per chat room [here](http://t5atmosphere-lazan.rhcloud.com/chatdemo). [Here's the main class](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-atmosphere/blob/master/tapestry-atmosphere-demo/src/main/java/org/lazan/t5/atmosphere/demo/services/ChatManagerImpl.java) which sends the messages. You'll notice it sends messages to "rooms/%s/users" each time someone joins or leaves